# All parallel processes in foreach loop in R generating same results

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-foreach

I use `foreach()` loop to generate random arrays in parallel. But I am getting same results in all parallel process. How do I add randomness in each parallel process so that each process is different from each other?

```
library(doFuture)
library(foreach)

# Parallel programming
registerDoFuture()
plan(multicore, workers = 3)


res = foreach(iter = 1:3) %dopar%
{
  
  # generate random array
  x = runif(n = 5)
  
}
```

All arrays generated in parallel are same

```
> res
[[1]]
[1] 0.55882648 0.73863525 0.51284839 0.01454722 0.08909375

[[2]]
[1] 0.55882648 0.73863525 0.51284839 0.01454722 0.08909375

[[3]]
[1] 0.55882648 0.73863525 0.51284839 0.01454722 0.08909375
```

Comment: It must be related to the `RNGkind` in `set.seed`.  e.g. for me, it is working fine though.  Can you try changing to `set.seed(1, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")`

Comment: There is a warning which says `1: UNRELIABLE VALUE: One of the foreach() iterations (‘doFuture-1’) unexpectedly generated random numbers without declaring so. There is a risk that those random numbers are not statistically sound and the overall results might be invalid. To fix this, use '%dorng%' from the 'doRNG' package instead of '%dopar%'. This ensures that proper, parallel-safe random numbers are produced via the L'Ecuyer-CMRG method.`

Comment: For the protocol: At first run of `plan` I got a warning `...Forked processing ('multicore') is not supported when running R from RStudio...`. So I tried original code in console and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is warning message which suggests to use `%dorng%` from `doRNG` package if we run the OP's code

> Warning messages:
> 1: UNRELIABLE VALUE: One of the foreach() iterations (‘doFuture-1’) unexpectedly generated random numbers without declaring so. There is a risk that those random numbers are not statistically sound and the overall results might be invalid. To fix this, use '%dorng%' from the 'doRNG' package instead of '%dopar%'. This ensures that proper, parallel-safe random numbers are produced via the L'Ecuyer-CMRG method. To disable this check, set option 'future.rng.onMisuse' to "ignore".
> ...

Therefore, load the package and use `%dorng%` inplace of `%dopar%`

```
library(doFuture)
library(foreach)
library(doRNG)

# Parallel programming
registerDoFuture()
plan(multicore, workers = 3)

res = foreach(iter = 1:3) %dorng%
 {
   # generate random array
   x = runif(n = 5)
 }
res
[[1]]
[1] 0.1058127 0.4715034 0.9921409 0.3633179 0.9830486

[[2]]
[1] 0.2801489 0.1372907 0.6491732 0.6267578 0.1657053

[[3]]
[1] 0.8981384 0.8950956 0.4003182 0.9338281 0.9706626
attr(,"rng")
attr(,"rng")[[1]]
[1]       10407    41337137 -1038536386  -420834137  1745650876  2038421133 -1613694998

attr(,"rng")[[2]]
[1]       10407 -1775499178   -92726601 -1608089308   992801654   241903385  2115481412

attr(,"rng")[[3]]
[1]       10407  1979572086 -1800896478  -210258865   856919030   298818868  1787849826
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I have a follow up question - If I train 10 ANNs in keras in parallel using foreach loop (Each training should ideally start from a different random initial weights.). Does that mean %dopar% starts all the ANN training from same initial random weights. And if I use %doRNG% it will allow each training to start from a different initial weights.

Comment: @SiH I guess so.  Otherwise, you may have to add the `set.seed` with `kind` value as `set.seed(1, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")` sing `%dopar%`

Comment: So if I train 10 ANNs (each take 1 hour) in parallel. I should use %doRNG% instead of %dopar% to ensure different initial random weights in all parallel training.

Comment: @SiH Try it on a small data with 2 in parallel and check the output before you run the code on the full data

Comment: okay thanks, thats a good idea.. The rdocumentation writes - %dorng% provides an alternative operator %dopar%, that ensures reproducible foreach loops. What is meant by `reproducible foreach loops`, I just want each parallel training process to start from different random weights

Comment: @SiH You may check [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_6245/slides/chapter4.pdf) about the reproducibility.  i.e. if you are running the same code multiple times, you would have to return the same output right?

Comment: @SiH What i meant is that you run your code couple of times and see the output `set.seed(24);
res = foreach(iter = 1:3) %dopar%
 {
   
  # generate random array   x = runif(n = 5)
 
 }`. If I do this again and check `identical(res, res2)#
[1] FALSE`

Comment: got it, thanks a lot